# What is the opposite of “patricide”?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What’s the opposite of the word *patricide*?

I’m looking for the word that describes the act (or the person, to keep in similar vein with *suicide*, *patricide*, etc.) of a father killing his son out of malice.

I’m not looking for *matricide*, which I consider to be a related but not opposite term for *patricide*.

Comment: Isn't this easily googled? 'filicide'?

Comment: @Mitch: how can "filicide" be easily googled when you don't know the word to begin with?

Comment: @RiMMERΨ: you want to look for all '-cide's? look for two different ones, patricide and suicide. It's in the first paragraph of the first google hit at the wikipedia article on patricide.

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of research and effort into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Dictionary:
**fil·i·cide** /ˈfiləˌsīd/ Noun: 1. The killing of one's child. 2. A person who kills their child.

Comment: Very interesting numbers from wikipedia: "A 1999 US Department of Justice study concluded that between 1976 and 1997 in the United States, mothers were responsible for a higher share of children killed during infancy, while fathers were more likely to have been responsible for the murders of children age 8 or older.[1] [...] Parents were responsible for 61% of children murders under the age of five; filicide is the third leading cause of death amongst American children five to fourteen years old.[2]"